# Jenkins builds incorporating NVM suddenly failing (Failing to fork bash)

Tags: node.js, bash, jenkins, nvm

On our Jenkins box we are getting the following error: *"ERROR: Failed to fork bash"* when building nodejs servers. This issue occurs randomly:

```sh
$ bash -c "test -f $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
NVM is already installed

$ bash -c "export > env.txt"
$ bash -c "NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh --no-use && NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist nvm install v10.17.0 && nvm use v10.17.0 && export > env.txt"
Version 'v10.17.0' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
ERROR: Failed to fork bash
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it appears as if the error is `Failed to fork` - followed then by the process that cannot be launched - in this case `bash`. I did not initially realize this.

`Unable to fork` because of insufficient resources.

We managed to determine that server resources were low, and that by increasing resources this problem seems to have gone away.

Solved - for now...